# Using ternary operator in ng-submit in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<form ng-if="userCtrl.show"
    ng-submit="userCtrl.showOtpForm : userCtrl.verifyOtp() ? userCtrl.sendOtpToEmail()" >......</form>
```

I want to use ternary operator in `ng-submit`. Like when the show variable in `userController` evaluates to true then `verifyOtp()` function should be called else the other one.  But I've been getting a syntax error.

Comment: You've got it the wrong way around, should be `condition?true:false`

Comment: It seems question asked without even looking ternary operator syntax.

Comment: @Ved maybe he was looking into mirror while copying the code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ternary doesn't look right, try this:

```
 ng-submit="userCtrl.showOtpForm ? userCtrl.verifyOtp() : userCtrl.sendOtpToEmail()"
```

Comment: Ohh my God! Such a silly mistake...thanks Liam.